# many missing .lib files in the installed OpenCV3.2.0 for Windows 10 64bit

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, lib

I am using a code that depends on the opencv libraries however the one I downloaded from the web only has the `opencv_core320.lib`. How can I install opencv so that I will access to all these libraries that I have in the input section of Linker in the Visual Studio 2015?

```
cv2.lib
opencv_imgcodecs300.lib
opencv_superres300.lib
opencv_calib3d300.lib
opencv_imgproc300.lib
opencv_ts300.lib
opencv_core300.lib
opencv_ml300.lib
opencv_video300.lib
opencv_features2d300.lib
opencv_objdetect300.lib
opencv_videoio300.lib
opencv_flann300.lib
opencv_photo300.lib
opencv_videostab300.lib
opencv_hal300.lib
opencv_shape300.lib
opencv_highgui300.lib
opencv_stitching300.lib
```

I am not biased towards the version of OpenCV, it could be either 3.0.0 or 3.2.0. Here are some screenshot from the opencv that I have:
[image]

Additionally, I have this error which makes sense because it couldn't find cv2.lib in the lib directory I have told the linker. So I assume I have installed OpenCV wrong way.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK1181 cannot open input file 'cv2.lib'    OpenARK-SDK C:\openark_mona\OpenARK\OpenARK-SDK\LINK    1
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with openvc, but you could try to remove all these libs and replace with new single lib: `opencv_world320.lib`

From [What is opencv_world](http://answers.opencv.org/question/3614/what-is-opencv_world-package-in-opencv-243-rc/):

> The new super-module modestly called opencv_world has been introduced.
>   It combines all the other modules selected by user and thus it's much
>   more convenient for redistribution, comparing to ~20 shared libraries
>   libopencv_core, libopencv_imgproc etc.

Looks like opencv_world now replaces all that zoo of libs that used to come with opencv.

Comment: awww thanks! I'll let you know if that would work for me.